# How to add horizontal spacing only between parent, but no siblings

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

Probably, it's a simple question, but I cannot comprehend it. In the simplified layout (pic) I need to align utter the tables with the content of the header above and preserve horizontal space between siblings. I'm struggling with what I should use: margins, padding or a combination of them. Perhaps, there're other flaws in the code, please tell me if you noticed.
[image]

How can I achieve this?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layout {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.indicators {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: 1px dashed green;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.indicator__item {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="layout">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Text</h1>
      <div class="combobox">
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="">1</option>
        </select>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="">2</option>
        </select>
        <button>Update</button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="indicators">
      <div class="indicator__item">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lorem.</th>
              <th>Quae!</th>
              <th>Deserunt!</th>
              <th>Aspernatur.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Natus.</td>
              <td>Voluptatibus.</td>
              <td>Modi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Tempore.</td>
              <td>Ipsam!</td>
              <td>Voluptas.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Sint.</td>
              <td>Error!</td>
              <td>Fugit.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Aut.</td>
              <td>Ipsa.</td>
              <td>Suscipit!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Quis.</td>
              <td>Corporis.</td>
              <td>Dolorem!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Optio!</td>
              <td>Veritatis?</td>
              <td>Nihil?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Nesciunt.</td>
              <td>Obcaecati.</td>
              <td>Error!</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="indicator__item">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lorem.</th>
              <th>Ipsa?</th>
              <th>Rerum.</th>
              <th>Tempore.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Placeat.</td>
              <td>Nemo.</td>
              <td>Sint?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Voluptas.</td>
              <td>Sunt!</td>
              <td>Earum.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Quia.</td>
              <td>Vitae.</td>
              <td>Officiis!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Labore?</td>
              <td>Omnis!</td>
              <td>Dolorum.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Nulla!</td>
              <td>Laboriosam.</td>
              <td>Assumenda.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="indicator__item">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lorem.</th>
              <th>Saepe.</th>
              <th>Ipsam.</th>
              <th>Quasi!</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Libero.</td>
              <td>Laboriosam.</td>
              <td>Deserunt!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Facere!</td>
              <td>Ipsum.</td>
              <td>Praesentium.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Ex.</td>
              <td>Praesentium.</td>
              <td>Molestias.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Natus!</td>
              <td>Assumenda.</td>
              <td>Consequatur.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Eveniet.</td>
              <td>Nostrum.</td>
              <td>Ex.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="indicator__item">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lorem.</th>
              <th>Esse?</th>
              <th>Aperiam.</th>
              <th>Laboriosam.</th>
              <th>Laboriosam.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem.</td>
              <td>Corrupti.</td>
              <td>Facere.</td>
              <td>Expedita.</td>
              <td>Exercitationem.</td>
              <td>Expedita.</td>
              <td>Quos?</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Is this the result you need? - https://ibb.co/wRvDFH0

Comment: ...or like that? - https://ibb.co/6XnV5Mq

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `margin` rule `margin: 10px 20px` from class `.indicator__item`. And add `gap` and `padding` rule (for top and bottom margin) in `.indicators` class. Like this:

```
.indicators {
  ...
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

I set it to **20px** at my discretion, but you can specify any value. The `gap` value must equal the `padding` value.

Snippet:

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layout {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.indicators {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    outline: 1px dashed green;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.indicator__item {
    /*margin: 10px 20px;*/
    outline: 1px solid red;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main class="layout">
            <header class="header">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <div class="combobox">
                    <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="">1</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <button>Update</button>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="indicators">
                <div class="indicator__item">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lorem.</th>
                                <th>Quae!</th>
                                <th>Deserunt!</th>
                                <th>Aspernatur.</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Natus.</td>
                                <td>Voluptatibus.</td>
                                <td>Modi.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Tempore.</td>
                                <td>Ipsam!</td>
                                <td>Voluptas.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Sint.</td>
                                <td>Error!</td>
                                <td>Fugit.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Aut.</td>
                                <td>Ipsa.</td>
                                <td>Suscipit!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Quis.</td>
                                <td>Corporis.</td>
                                <td>Dolorem!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Optio!</td>
                                <td>Veritatis?</td>
                                <td>Nihil?</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Nesciunt.</td>
                                <td>Obcaecati.</td>
                                <td>Error!</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="indicator__item">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lorem.</th>
                                <th>Ipsa?</th>
                                <th>Rerum.</th>
                                <th>Tempore.</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Placeat.</td>
                                <td>Nemo.</td>
                                <td>Sint?</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Voluptas.</td>
                                <td>Sunt!</td>
                                <td>Earum.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Quia.</td>
                                <td>Vitae.</td>
                                <td>Officiis!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Labore?</td>
                                <td>Omnis!</td>
                                <td>Dolorum.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Nulla!</td>
                                <td>Laboriosam.</td>
                                <td>Assumenda.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="indicator__item">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lorem.</th>
                                <th>Saepe.</th>
                                <th>Ipsam.</th>
                                <th>Quasi!</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Libero.</td>
                                <td>Laboriosam.</td>
                                <td>Deserunt!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Facere!</td>
                                <td>Ipsum.</td>
                                <td>Praesentium.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Ex.</td>
                                <td>Praesentium.</td>
                                <td>Molestias.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Natus!</td>
                                <td>Assumenda.</td>
                                <td>Consequatur.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Eveniet.</td>
                                <td>Nostrum.</td>
                                <td>Ex.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="indicator__item">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lorem.</th>
                                <th>Esse?</th>
                                <th>Aperiam.</th>
                                <th>Laboriosam.</th>
                                <th>Laboriosam.</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lorem.</td>
                                <td>Corrupti.</td>
                                <td>Facere.</td>
                                <td>Expedita.</td>
                                <td>Exercitationem.</td>
                                <td>Expedita.</td>
                                <td>Quos?</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! After your reply I did it like this: I discarded padding and margin in .indicator__item, add flex: 1 1 34%  and set gap: 10px 20px in .indicator

https://jsfiddle.net/rk7wn63L/

Comment: @vyenkv, `gap: 10px 20px` - good approach. Glad to help.